# Default Login for Docker Image of Superset?

Tags: apache-superset

Installed superset using the docker image, but I was never prompted for an admin account creation. I've tried admin/admin and admin/superset combinations but nothing is working.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should have been prompted to create an admin account at the end of Docker build.

If you missed it, you can use following commands to create a new admin account:

```
docker-compose exec superset fabmanager create-admin --app superset
```

Or

```
docker-compose exec superset bash -c 'export FLASK_APP=superset && flask fab create-admin'
```

Make sure you are in the `contrib/docker` folder and your containers are up and running.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using docker-compose, the admin password can be set in docker/docker-init.sh file. If you have already run `docker-compose up`, you have to run `docker-compose down -v` to remove settings before running `docker-compose up` again.

Answer (score 2):

Username: `admin` 
Password: `admin`

This combination worked for me.